# polkit rules to prevent shutdown / reboot does not work

Tags: linux, shutdown, policykit

I am trying to prevent reboot a Debian 11 machine from the KDE start menu. However the following policy does not work:

```
[michael@vps /etc/polkit-1/rules.d]> cat /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-admin-shutdown-reboot.rules 
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-ignore-inhibit" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-ignore-inhibit" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-parameter" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-firmware-setup" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-boot-loader-menu" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.set-reboot-to-boot-loader-entry" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-ignore-inhibit" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions"
    ) {
        return polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN;
    }
});
```

`pkcheck -u -p $$ -a org.freedesktop.login1.reboot; echo $?` returns 2 if run on an ssh session (expected), but 0 if on the physical machine logged in via SDDM. What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What distribution and what polkit version are you running?

Comment: Debian 11, Polkit 0.105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polkit package in Debian 11 and earlier does not support JavaScript-based rules. Debian maintains a patch that replaces the JS-format rules engine with the older `.pkla` configuration format.

In this format, the rules would look like this:

```
[Require authentication for shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off*;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot*
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=auth_admin
```

See [pklocalauthority(8)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pklocalauthority.8.html) for the format documentation.

Comment: I have upgraded Debian and the Javascript rules now work. However the restart button still exists on the start menu. After I press it, the screen turns back and I have to restart sddm using root from another terminal to restore responsiveness. What should I do instead such that it should prompt me authentication when I try to restart?

Answer (score -1):

The hanging GUI seems to come from a missing authentication agent. I use `return polkit.Result.NO;` and it works as expected.  Also removed packages `pkexec`, `policykit-1`, and `polkitd-pkla`.